# Metal Shading Language - SDF and Ray marching

Tags: swift, kernel, cpu, metal

**TL;DR:**
I want to make `Constructive Solid Geometry` app with `Signed Distance Functions`, but not sure how to split the serial process and parallel process between `cpu` and `kernel`.

I have been exploring a lot with `Signed Distance Functions` and `Ray marching` with `Metal` lately and trying to make a simple `Constructive Solid Geometry` with `Metal`. However, after many rounds of coding and reading, I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

Issue:
All of the `SDF`example is kind of hardcode every calculation is done in the `kernel`. For example:

```
float map(float3 p){

float a = ball(p,1.0);
float b = ball(p+float3(1.0,0.0,0.0),1.0);

return min(a,b);
}
```

so you will get 2 balls sitting side by side. 
But I want to add, position and rotate the ball at runtime dynamically.

Solution01:

All the `map()` calculation will be done in `swift`, then pass down to `kernel` to process. But that will be slow because you will have to process the calculation for the whole screen using `cpu`, then only pass down to `kernel`, which, the best job to use `kernel`, has been robbed by `cpu`.

Solution02:

Send an `array` of `object` with all the attributes to `kernel`:

```
var objects = [{size:1.0,position:float3(0.0,0.0,0.0)},
{size:1.0,position:float3(1.0,0.0,0.0)}, ...]
```

Then process it based on the attributes using `for` loop in `map()` in the `kernel`:

```
float map(float3 p, float3 objects[]){//<-- objects[] is pseudo code for easy illustration purposes
float a;
for(int i = 1; i < objects.size(); i++){
a = min(ball(p + objects[i].position,objects[i].size),ball(p + objects[i-1].position,objects[i-1].size));
}

return a;
}
```

However, I am not sure if is the right way of doing because the `for` loop might overwork the `kernel`.

Solution03:

process and compile `map()` in `cpu`, then send the whole functions to `kernel`, then (somehow, I am not sure how) convert the functions for all the `ray- marching` use.

My questions:

Which is the right solution to adopt?

Personally I would be grateful if I can implement **Solution03**, but I am not sure that is possible.

**Solution02** is not bad too. However, when the objects get complicated, the for loop will be too long. and I am not sure how `kernel` will handle this serial process while it is best for parallel processing.

**Solution01** is not bad, if I don't have to process the whole screen resolution before I send to `kernel`.

Or:
Any other ways that people actually use and I am not aware of?

**Update01:**

I just test out **Solution02** and after 3 objects, the `FPS` drop to 5, obviously is not acceptable.